# Alternate option for a Data Player plugin for GPS in qgis

Tags: qgis, gps, qgis-plugins

I found a plugin for QGIS to play a GPS Track. (Data player plugin).The Problem is I can not read .gpx File with this plugin.

Is there another option?

Comment: Sorry, I CAN'T read .gpx files with this plugin.

Comment: might be helpful for you http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42785/import-gpx-file-to-qgis-and-correct-apparent-crs-problems

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the Data Player plugin only plays data that was collected by the Data Gather plugin. A simple GPX file does not contain all the information that is written by the Gather plugin. That plugin uses NMEA input, not GPX.

The GPS Tool allows you to import a GPX file, but not playing it.

Comment: As Andre pointed out, you must use the gps tool, this one allows you to read your gpx. In order to play with it (edit it I assume) you must save your track as a shape file, and put it in edit mode. Hope it helps

Comment: Would be nice if the time manager plugin could simulate the playing, but I did not get it working with the GPX timestamps...